# How do I migrate a Kickstart site from one server to another?

Tags: migrations, commerce

I created a site using [Commerce Kickstart](https://www.drupal.org/project/commerce_kickstart).
Then I added all the products and stuff. Now I want to move this site on a new server as it is.

I have downloaded all the files from the original site. Also exported the database.

Is it possible to use these files and database to migrate the site on new server with different domain name as well as different database name?

If no, what should I do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- First install the [Backup and Migrate module](https://www.drupal.org/project/backup_migrate) into your existing site, then after enabling it, go to

> /admin/config/system/backup_migrate

- Click **Backup now** under the backup tab. Store this file
- Now take backup of your files from existing site
- Either rename settings.php to some other name or just remove it
- Now upload the backed up files to desired destination
- Just enter your new URL, it will take you to

> yoursite.xxx/install.php

- Now follow the usual method of installing your site (enter new database credentials)
- You'll be redirected to a fresh and basic Drupal site
- Now go to modules, enable Backup and Migrate module
- Go to configuration page of the same, click the **Restore** tab, now upload previously downloaded file (using same module)
- Click on **Restore Now**
- That's it. Your site is restored!

Answer (score 1):

1. drush ard
   (https://drushcommands.com/drush-7x/core/archive-dump/)
2. copy backup file to the new server
3. drush arr (https://drushcommands.com/drush-7x/core/archive-restore/)
4. done

Comment: Hi @Lóránt, welcome to Drupal Aswers. Thank you for your answer; could you elaborate a bit more instead of just posting the commands to use?

Answer (score 0):

This should definitely be possible. Upload all of your files to your new server and create a new blank database.

Make sure to delete your existing settings.php file and create a new one from default.settings.php. You can find this file in sites/default/

Run the install script - yourdomain.com/install.php

Now upload your database to the new database.

Alternatively, you can upload your database to the new database and change the settings in settings.php manually.

Be careful to make the settings.php file secure by either running this: chmod 644 sites/default/settings.php on the command line or changing it via filezilla/your FTP client.